# Access to a element of array value in json from dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this const variable in flutter:

```
static const questions = [
    {
      "question": "question",
      "answers": ["1", "2"],
      "message":
          "message",
    }, 
]
```

how to access to "1" from dart??

I try using `QuestionContent.questions[0]["answers"][0].`
But I got error `"The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use:

```
Text((QuestionContent.questions[0] as Map<String, dynamic>)['answers'][0] ?? '')
```

or:

```
Text((questions[0]['answers'] as List<String>)[0]),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
const questions = [
  {
    "question": "question",
    "answers": ["1", "2"],
    "message":
    "message",
  },
];
Map<String, Object> question = questions[0];
List<String> answers = question["answers"] as List<String>;
String firstAnswer = answers.elementAt(0);
```

The reason you get the error is the compiler could not tell whether your `QuestionContent.questions[0]["answers"]` is null or not:

[image]